# MtGox - trusted vs verified

Tags: mtgox, trust, verification

What is the difference between a "trusted", "verified" and other accounts at MtGox? In order to get "verified", one needs to provide them with photo ID and utility bill, but how does one get "trusted"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the time of this writing, "Verified" Accounts are eligible for monthly/daily withdrawal limits up to 10 times the default daily amount and 5 times the default monthly amount, while "Trusted" Accounts are eligible for monthly/daily withdrawal limits up to 100 times the default daily amount and 50 times the default monthly amount.

For verified status it is enough to send by email a scan of the ID and bill, and they only need to be translated if they don't include an English name. For trusted status, physical copies of the documents must be sent by mail, they must be certified by an apostille, and if they are not completely in English they must have a notarized translation.

The withdrawal limits for normal / verified / trusted accounts are:

```
Daily BTC: 400 / 4,000 / 40,000
Monthly BTC: No limit
Daily USD: 1,000 / 10,000 / 100,000
Monthly USD: 10,000 / 50,000 / 500,000
```

You can also choose to lower your limit if you want.

Comment: What's the default daily?

Comment: @ripper234: Edited to add.

Comment: Daily BTC limits were quadrupled some time ago, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a verified user at Mt.Gox and when I go to withdrawal funds link they show me this text

- BTC : You can still withdraw up to 100.00000000 BTC provided you have
  enough on your account (your limit is 100.00000000 BTC per 24 hours )
- USD : You can still withdraw up to $1,000.00000 provided you have enough on your account (your limit is $1,000.00000 per 24 hours and
  $10,000.00000 per 30 days)